# Python Web data collecting

Tags: python, database, arrays, web-applications, web

I am new to Python, but I have a challenge that I am trying to complete. This is not class related but I am trying to learn how to used websites with python.

I want to do the following:

Go to this website: http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=FB&m=2012-12

Store all strikes and asks that correspond to those strikes below the market price into arrays named strike and ask

See picture for clarification:
[image]

Example arrays that corresponds the picture would be:

strike = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

ask = [10.20,8.20,7.20,6.30,5.30,4.40,3.50,2.75,2.05,1.45]

It would not grab 21 - 27 strikes because that is above the market price. Please let me know if this is possible to do with python. Thank you.

Since this is NOT an assignment, any other programming language that could do this easier is also appreciated, but I need that data stored in arrays

Comment: does yahoo finance have an api? i'm too tired to check myself..

Comment: If there isn't such an API, you can try to parse the HTML and get what you want. [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a good choice.

Comment: @Gevorg They do not have an API for options

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I just realized that you're refering to the options page on Yahoo! Finance and not the basic stock service.  I'm sure they have an API for it, but like the stock one, it's probably not published.  I'm interested in this, so I might keep looking.

They have a web service that returns stock data in a CSV format.  Here's the basic format of a stock query:

> http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=nl1

The two GET parameters this takes are the symbol list (designated with the 's=') and the format of the resulting CSV file (designated by the 'f='). So in the above example, I used Google's ticker symbol and the format was to get the last price.  You can use more than one symbol and more than one format to get the stock data you need.

For a full list of format variables, check out this [page](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm).

So all you really have to do is form the correct URL and use the urllib2 library's urllib2.open(url) method to get the CSV file and then it's just doing some basic CSV parsing with the csv library.

Alternatively, there are libraries out there that have all this built for you.  I haven't used any of them but I'll post a few as comments if I can remember them.

Comment: Thanks, but thats the one I found, but I am looking for the options page

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is scrape the results and store it in the list(I assume). You can scrape the page using a python library called lxml. http://lxml.de/

Let me point you at a similar tutorial, http://www.techchorus.net/web-scraping-lxml

Go through xpath once before starting with the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yahoo does have an API: http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv, which may be passed some arguments; see https://github.com/bunburya/bunbot/blob/master/utils/stock.py for more details.

Answer (score 0):

What you need and want is [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Here's an example snippet.

```
  1 from pandas.io.data import DataReader                                                                                        
  2 from datetime import datetime
  3  
  4 dr = DataReader("YHOO", "yahoo")
  5  
  6 print "Yahoo's stock price over time"
  7 print dr["Volume"]
  8  
  9 yh_by_date = DataReader("YHOO",  "yahoo", datetime(2009,1,1))
 10  
 11 print "We want to restrict it based on specific dates"
 12 print yh_by_date["Adj Close"][-100:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your replies. I was able to do this using beautiful soup

;)